# What exactly are transactions in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

So whenever a transaction is started in Spring then does a new thread start or something? How exactly are these transactions implemented in Spring?

Comment: [This chapter explains it all.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: Transactions are about signaling between the JVM and the database (or other external systems), they have nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Okay then how are they implemented if threads arenot used? I know I can read the whole chapetr and all but I am in a little hurry so it would be great if you could give me some vague idea.